# MonoDevelop can't handle read-only files

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, perforce, readonly

I'm using MonoDevelop with MonoTouch. When I add an .NET assembly reference to my project, MonoDevelop will copy that .dll file into the bin/iPhone/Release/xxxx.app directory during the build process. Then later in the build process, it will modify that file and strip out unused stuff.

The problem is, if that file is read-only, MonoDevelop fails the build process because it can't modify (its copy of) the file later. This makes it very difficult to use a source control system like Perforce because Perforce keeps all files read-only until you check them out.

All I want is for MonoDevelop to make the file writable when it copies it into bin/iPhone/Release/xxxx.app, which it should always do since it owns that copy of the file.

Does anyone know a way to make MonoDevelop do this, or any other way around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, not something that really should be "answered" on SO. I recommend you report the bug on [Novell's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.novell.com/index.cgi) or worst-case ask the question on IRC in #monodevelop on irc.gimp.net.

Comment: Yes it's a bug but I thought someone might know a workaround. My experience with MonoDevelop and MonoTouch is that there are bits of tribal knowledge that one must know in order to get around issues like this. In any case, I filed a bug here: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=677924

Comment: Please fill all bugs in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com since Mono, MonoDevelop, MonoTouch... (commercial and open source software) are now under Xamarin's leadership.

Answer (score 1):

Perforce doesn't have to keep everything read-only till checked out. Use p4 typemap and the +w  modifier. You do then have to remember to check the file out if its not done by a plug-in or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (until a fix is available) you can try to add a post-build step, inside your project, that will remove the read-only attribute from the assembly file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You could set your Perforce client workspace so that all files are writable, even if they are not opened for edit.  Check the `allwrite` option at http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/02_config.html#1067985